# How can I auto indent on Ubuntu?

Tags: indentation

I want that when I insert any bracket it automatically inserts another closing bracket in next line and indents automatically.
It would help a lot in my programming.

Comment: About which editor are we talking?

Answer (score 2):

For autoindent, any number of text editors can do this.
I like Leafpad for a basic notepad tool. It can autoindent.

Auto closing brackets: For html I'd start with Bluefish.
Also Sea Monkey the full edition comes with a GUI html editor.

Do you want to edit html or languages like python, or perl?

For language programming, there are feature full text editors such as geany or kate. These can automatically add the closing brackets and auto indent.

If you want a full desktop programming and debugging environment you might desire sublime, or eclipse.

Do any of these options satisfy your quest for code editing?

Answer (score 1):

This is more a feature of your editor than Ubuntu.

Have you looked at, vi or emacs (aka xemacs).

None of them add the closing } in the configurations I'm aware of, but do auto indenting. And no, they aren't really geared towards GUIs, they still show their roots in tty time. But then again, mousing around isn't efficient use of your time anyway.

For specific IDEs, check out eclipse, GUI to the core. There should be others, but in my experience they are memory and CPU hogs, and too inflexible for my taste.